# java stream groupingBy embedded objects

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have couple of objects:

```
public class RequestHostel {
    private Hostel name;
}
```

and

```
public class Hostel {
    private String value;
}
```

and I would like to know if it is possible to group by the value of `Hostel`, something like

```
.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RequestHostel::getName::getValue, counting()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot chain method reference, but you can use lambda:

```
.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(rh -> rh.getName().getValue(), counting()))
```

Or if you're not using these objects, you can simply map them:

```
.stream().map(RequestHostel::getName).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Hotel::getValue, counting()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot chain *method references* as you did. But yes, you can use *lambda* for that:

```
Map<String, Long> countGroupedByValue = requestHostels.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(requestHostel -> requestHostel.getName().getValue(),
                Collectors.counting()));
```